# What is a Reactive User Interface? Where did the term come from?

Tags: design, gui, ui

I heard about Reactive User Interfaces in a React course. I would like to understand the concept, but was unable to find reliable sources. Best I could find is that they are some sort of declarative UI representation, and I would like to confirm if that really is the case. Can someone give me an explanation of this term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Wikipedia page on [Reactive User Interfaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_user_interface) but you should probably consider it outdated.

Then there are a couple of frameworks for creating user interfaces that have the word react or reactive in the name. The intent here is probably to convey that they represent a modern event driven paradigm.

Which brings us to the modern day meaning of reactive in the software world: *a shift from call-based, request-response centered systems to pure message based systems.*

YouTube channel Continuous Delivery has an excellent video on [Reactive Systems](https://youtu.be/eRxLfUIMJwk). This is Dave Farley's channel, there is also a [goto; talk](https://youtu.be/tKRa0O7aepo) on the matter by him.

Comment: I've just watched Dave Farley's video: that's about _reactive software architectures_ in general (big, distributed, resilient & flexible networking/messaging-based systems), it's barely relevant for UIs. I mean UIs have been message-based pretty much all across their history, and they are also flexible and all..., but these are not useful traits to define what's supposed to make a UI "reactive". So, it's pretty hopelessly vague still. (People even argue about whether React is reactive, given all the ambiguity around this... No wonder the Wikipedia page is a joke.)

Comment: Reading back my answer it occurs to me I never addressed the core question "where the term comes from". Reactive basically means event driven. A state changes (in the UI case because of a user action) which triggers a response, which raises some events. It is a fine line between command based, active, call-based on the one hand and event driven, passive, message based on the other hand, it is a matter of perspective: what is considered part of the system and the logic? In other words: it is the system initiating an action versus the system responding (reacting) to a change in the environment.

Comment: @MartinMaat I think you're close, but the translation from "state change" to "action" isn't required (even if it is happening deep inside the framework).  Generally speaking, there is some data representation of state, and it is synchronized (both ways) with the UI.